# Numerical Integration over region with singularities

Tags: integration, matlab, singularity, sagemath, numerical-calculus

I am trying to integrate the following $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\cos(x)}}dx$$ and I am stuck on how to proceed using Matlab or Sage.

Comment: This will not be integrable at all, as can be easily seen by asymptotic expansion near $x=0$, where the integrand behaves like $1/x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to complement the other answers.

There is an easier function to use instead of the [quadgk](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quadgk.html). It is the [integral](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) function. They both do the same think, but the name "integral" is easier to remember, easier to find and easier to use. There is a good discussion about it on [Mathworks blog](https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2016/05/23/modernization-of-numerical-integration-from-quad-to-integral/).

Type it on MATLAB, and both functions will return `Inf` - which means the integral diverges.

```
f = @(x) 1./sqrt(1-cos(x))
integral(f,0,2*pi)
quadgk(f,0,2*pi)
```

As @Claude Leibovici noticed, however, we can evaluate the integral if the limits are not $0$ and $2\pi$.

```
format long
eps = 1e-2;
integral(f,eps,2*pi-eps)
```

And the result is

```
16.946414949423382
```

Not exactly the value, but pretty good. We can even get better results [reducing the tolerances](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html#namevaluepairarguments) on the integral function.

Answer (score 1):

This integral is a type II improper integral as the interval of integration includes a point at which the output values of the integrand approach $\pm \infty$. In this case, $f(x) \rightarrow \infty$ as $x \rightarrow 0$ and as $x \rightarrow 2\pi$, both of which comprise the limits of integration.

We proceed by examining the domain of $f$ and noting that it is in fact continuous and therefore integrable on $(0,2\pi)$. Thus, we choose some arbitrary element in the interval of integration for which $f$ is defined, say $\pi$, and then add the limits of two integrals as follows:

$$\lim_{a \rightarrow 0} \int_a^\pi \frac{1}{\sqrt[]{1-cos\theta}}d\theta + \lim_{b \rightarrow 2\pi} \int_\pi^{b} \frac{1}{\sqrt[]{1-cos\theta}}d\theta$$

First, compute the integrals irrespective of the limits. Then, after you have obtained the antiderivatives in terms of $a,b$ and $\theta$, solve the limits.

Whether the integral converges or not remains to be seen, but this is a standard approach to solving such a problem. I believe current versions of Matlab are able to handle infinite limits. Look into **quadgk**.

Comment: That seems to be what I am looking for, but when I plug it into Matlab I still get Inf as my answer. This is what I am typing in, if it helps,  f = @(x) 1./sqrt(1-cos(x));
q = quadgk(f, 0, pi). I also tried splitting up the integral into two as you suggested and it was still giving me inf.

Comment: Matlab is in fact giving you the correct answer. Inf means "infinity," so it's telling you the integral diverges (i.e. it does not converge on a finite number).

Answer (score 1):

The antiderivative is not a major problem and then
$$I(\epsilon)=\int_\epsilon^{2\pi-\epsilon}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-\cos(x)}}=2 \sqrt{2} \log \left(\cot \left(\frac{\epsilon }{4}\right)\right)$$
Using Taylor expansion built at $\epsilon=0$ gives
$$I(\epsilon)=-2 \sqrt{2} \log \left(\frac{\epsilon }{4}\right)-\frac{\epsilon
   ^2}{12 \sqrt{2}}+O\left(\epsilon ^4\right)$$
Computing  $$I\left(\frac{1}{100}\right)=2 \sqrt{2} \log \left(\cot \left(\frac{1}{400}\right)\right)\approx 16.9464149494303$$ while the above truncated series would give          $\color{red}              {16.94641494943}89$